# Populate Pandas/Dask Dataframe from sqlite query on column value

Tags: python, sqlite, pandas, dask

I have a dask dataframe (generated from a pandas dataframe) which contains a columns of values .
Based on one of these columns I would like

I am currently trying to do this with a SQLite3 Database and doing a 
"select class from tableName where value between 1000.3 and 1000.4"

Pandas copes okay with this (albeit slowly) but when I run the function against the dask dataframe - I find I can't connect to the database globally as I get the following error...

```
ProgrammingError: ('SQLite objects created in a thread can only be used in that same thread.The object was created in thread id 8632 and this is thread id 6936', 'occurred at index 0')
```

As a result I have to connect to the database in each function call ...

```
def classify(s):
    con = lite.connect('../biggishDB.db')
    cur = con.cursor()    
    targetValue = s['values']

    minValue = targetValue *(1.-(5./1000000))
    maxValue = targetValue *(1.+(5./1000000))
    #print(os.getcwd())   
    selectStatement ="select class from myTable where values between %f and %f" % (minValue, maxValue)
    cur.execute(selectStatement)
    data = cur.fetchone()
    con.close()
    return data[0]

myDaskDataframe['class'] = myDaskDataframe.apply(classify, axis =1).compute()
```

This is very slow and I would like to avoid it if possible.

The database is about 2Gb in size - and I have considered if it's better in some other form . Unfortunately as the class name is a string pandas and dask both choke on it.

Do you have any suggestions as to how I can speed this up ?